# Drupal 7 theme "Busy" customization

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am a starter of Drupal 7.

I like the "Busy" theme a lot, especially this one in its screenshot of demos.

[image]

Yet, after I installed this theme, it seemed pretty far from what it looks like in the screenshot above. I tried to customize it but so far, I did not make much progress.

I see a lot of people saying this theme is good. The usage statistic shows a lot of websites are using this theme. I do like its neat layout, but as a starter, I really need some advice on how to work with this theme. How to make it look like the screenshot?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,

Milo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you having trouble with?
I don't know your level of experience with Drupal so I'm just going to give you a couple ideas.

If you go to (yourSiteName)/admin/structure/block/demo/busy it will show a demo of where you can place blocks on the page to make your site look more like the picture.

(yourSiteName)/admin/appearance/settings/busy will take you to the settings screen where you can change colors and toggle features on and off.

(yourSiteName)/admin/structure/block will take you to the blocks page where you can change the layout of each block and also configure individual blocks.

I hope this helps, if you can give a more detailed question, you'll probably get a better answer